# Image with hyperlink in reStructuredText

Tags: image, restructuredtext, docutils

I am trying to add an image with an external link.

```
|facebook| |tw|

.. |facebook| image:: http://www.summerbounce.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/facebook-logo-small.png 

.. |tw| image:: http://www.summerbounce.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/facebook-logo-small.png
```

Above code shows the images but how do I link these images to external sites?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `target` option do the trick.

```
|facebook| |tw|

.. |facebook| image:: http://www.summerbounce.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/facebook-logo-small.png 
                   :target: http://www.facebook.com 

.. |tw| image:: http://www.summerbounce.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/facebook-logo-small.png
             :target: http://www.twitter.com
```

Anyother better solution, always welcome.